# Trying to set a Firebase Realtime Database rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set the following rule for Firebase Realtime Database:

I want a user to be only able to read written entries in which a certain field would be the same as the id with which they are written in firebase.

To explain more clearly, this is a registry id currently in firebase:

8E4792606362B0F7

Registries like the one with that ID have, among another fields into them, this one:

sender_identifier: XXXXXXXXX

Some other registries with another id, might have a sender identifier which corresponds exactly to the id (in this case 8E4792606362B0F7).

I want the ones who have that sender identifier to be only able to read the data from the registry that precisely has that ID.

As much as I try to understand [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data?authuser=0), I cannot grasp how this would be done.

Only thing I have more or less clear is that first part of the rule should be "auth.id ==. But I'm not even sure of that.

To clarify more things I'm putting the SQL query that would be needed to retrieve the coincidences for this case, in the case that ID and sender_identifier where both fields in a table of relational database.

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE sender_identifier="8E4792606362B0F7"
```

This would return all IDs that are allowed to read from the registry with ID "8E4792606362B0F7", and this would be needed to do for each regitry entry.

How would it be possible to do such a thing?

Edit: I'm uploading an image to make more clear where is the problem:

[image]

As it can be seen the id inside the green ellipse matches with the sender_identifier with the other green ellipse, so, in this case, the ID in the green ellipse should be able to read data corresponding to the ID in the black circle, the opposite also happens, the ID in the black ellipse should be able to read data corresponding to the ID in the green ellipse, as the latter has a sender_identifier (also in a black ellipse) that matches.

If it were a problem to have what I call ID and the sender_identifier at a "different hierarchy", I could create a new field with the same info as what I call ID, as I'm the one generating it.

Comment: By entries, do you mean the documents you set up that stores different IDs in different documents, or just different fields in a single document? Because if it's the latter, you can't only return part of a single document.

Comment: @jackz314, if I understand you correctly, it's the first one, I mean, for example, a entry with ID=1 and a field into it with sender_identifier=2, another entry with ID=3 and a field into with sender_identifier=1, and so on.

Comment: I think I got it, just to make sure another thing, by sender_identifier, do you mean the user's auth.uid or a field that's being added to the database?

Comment: It's a field that's added inside of another entry, it can, under some conditions, be the same as an user's auth id for that entry, I'll put later an image to clarify even better if needed, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To match the user UID with your SENDER_IDENTIFIER and restrict read access with it, you should do:

```
"$YOUR_DOCUMENT": {
    ".read": "data.child('SENDER_IDENTIFIER').val() == auth.uid || 
    $YOUR_DOCUMENT === auth.uid"
}
```

where the incoming request's user must have a Firebase UID that matches the SENDER_IDENTIFIER in the entry or as the name of the entry in order to read the corresponding documents.

Comment: thanks but I cannot understand you answer, I've copied it and tried to put my own path, but it doesn't work. I added the image, in case it helps you.

Comment: I have updated my answer, see if this is what you meant

Comment: it doesn't work, but I think the problem is in that you are giving me firebase storage rules, and I'm using firebase database, not sure 100% but their rules seem to follow a different syntax: https://www.fullstackfirebase.com/firebase-storage/security-rules and https://www.fullstackfirebase.com/realtime-database/security-rules, I may be wrong as I'm pretty novice, but I think this is the deal.

Comment: Ok, now I see why you mentioned document... what a misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm using Cloud Firestore rules, not cloud storage, but it is similar. I'm assuming you are using Cloud Firestore, but apparently you are using realtime database, then the syntax should be different. But the general idea should be the same

Comment: I have updated the answer, this is the way if you're using realtime database. Also to clarify, using `auth.uid` is the only way to verify the incoming user since you can't check against any other payload with these security rules. So, if your user's UID might be different from the sender identifier, you need to take care of the verification yourself somewhere else.